# lighttpd domains and url matching

Tags: lighttpd

I'm trying to configure lighttpd so that:

- www.domain1.org/admin uses config1
- any other URL on www.domain1.org uses config2
- any url on www.domain2.org uses config2

So basically, domain1 and domain2 should use the same configuration except for when domain1 is accessed via an URL that starts with /admin

I tried so far a number of variations, including this one:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "domain1.org" {
  $HTTP["url"] =~ "^/admin" {
    // config1

    alias.url = ("/media/admin" => "/usr/share...",
                 "/static" => "/var/www/...")

    url.rewrite-once = (
      "^(/media/admin.*)$" => "$1",
      "^(/static.*)$" => "$1",
      "^/favicon\.ico$" => "/media/favicon.ico",
      "^(/.*)$" => "/application.fcgi$1",
    )
    server.document-root="/var/www/application"
    fastcgi.debug = 1

    fastcgi.server = (
      "/application.fcgi" => (
          "main" => (
              "socket" => "/var/www/application/application.sock",
              "check-local" => "disable",
          )
      ),
    )

  } else $HTTP["url"] !~ "^/admin" {
    // config2
  }

$HTTP["host"] !~ "domain1.org" {
   // config2
}
```

But no matter what, accessing domain1.org/admin yields a 404.

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: If it's returning 404 I would think that it's actually the contents of `config1` which is the problem.

Comment: Indeed, I figured out that accessing /admin fails, whereas accessing the fastcgi URL that is part of config1 works (/app.fcgi/admin). I will update the question with more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite:

> **NOTE: url rewriting does not work within a $HTTP["url"] conditional.**

Also the rewrites must always use the absolute path, so you should prefix your matches with /admin, and targets and the fastcgi.server match too.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed in https://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/2526